# Unique records from eloquent where certain field is maximum in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery

I am trying to do something like:

```
$this->inbox->where('status', 'COMPLETED')->get();
```

Which is returning me a list of records with repeated app_ids like:

```
1111
2222
3333
1111
2222
3333
3333
2222
```

And so on. I would like to have unique app_ids where del_index is maximum.
I tried this but failed:

```
$archive = $this->inbox->where('status', 'COMPLETED')->where(function($query){
            $query->max('del_index');
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

apply this should work

```
$archive = $this->inbox->select(\DB::RAW('DISTINCT("del_index")'))->where('status', 'COMPLETED')->orderBy('del_index','desc')->first();
```

Comment: This would give me just one record. I don't want one record. I want all records which have unique app_ids but the del_index is highest.

Comment: ok then use get() insetead of first(). Get will fetch all the records.